# Login no Django

Tags: python, django

Tenho uma página de login, preciso verificar quem está logando,
Exemplo: se for responsável do grupo A, direciona pra página com todos os usuários do grupo A, se for o responsável do grupo B, pra pagina de usuários do grupo B e assim por diante

models.py

```
class Grupo(models.Model):

    grupo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    divisao = models.ForeignKey(Divisao)
    responsavel = models.ForeignKey(User)

    @property
    def get_responsavel(self):
        return self.responsavel

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.grupo


class Perfil(User):
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ramal = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    data_inicio = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    data_fim = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    e_responsavel = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    vinculo = models.ForeignKey(Vinculo)
    grupos = models.ForeignKey(Grupo)
    divisao = models.ForeignKey(Divisao)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

views.py

```
def login_view(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())
    title = "Login"
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        login(request, user)
        print(request.user.is_authenticated())
        return redirect("/cadastro/sucesso")
        return render(request, 'sucesso.html')

        return redirect("/cadastro/sucesso")
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form':form, 'title':title})
```

Atualmente tenho a página de login que redireciona para a página de sucesso se for um usuário no django, não sei como fazer esse filtro de responsáveis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes você precisa responder algumas questões, o usuário pode ser responsável por mais de um grupo? (o seu modelo hoje permite). Vou supor que não, pois caso ele seja responsável por dois grupos para qual dos grupos você mandaria ele?

Então, considerando que o usuário só pode ser responsável por um grupo ficaria assim:

```
def login_view(request):
    print(request.user.is_authenticated())
    title = "Login"
    form = UserLoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)
        # ESSA LINHA PEGA O GRUPO QUE O SEU USUARIO É RESPONSAVEL
        grupo_responsavel = Grupo.objects.filter(responsavel=user)
        if not grupo_responsavel.exists():
          # CASO ELE NÃO SEJA RESPONSAVEL DE NENHUM GRUPO
          # SEU CODIGO AQUI (REDIRECIONAR PARA UMA PAGINA)

          # AQUI VOCÊ TEM TODOS OS PERFILS DO GRUPO QUE O USUARIO QUE ESTÁ LOGANDO É RESPONSAVEL
        usuarios_grupo = Perfil.objects.filte(grupos=grupo_responsavel)
        # PASSANDO A LISTA DE USUARIOS PARA O SEU TEMPLATE
        return render(request, 'pag.html', {'usuarios':usuarios_grupo, 'title':title})
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form':form, 'title':title})
```

Comment: Obrigada, resolveu!! Mas respondendo sua pergunta, o usuário pode sim ser responsável por mais de um grupo

Comment: Uma dúvida, eu não quero que essa lista de usuários fique na view do login, quero que fique na view lista, como faço pra comparar com o usuário logado igual você fez aí?